Suppose $∅ ≠ S ⊆ \mathbb{R}$ and is bounded below by $K$. Prove that if $M = \inf~S$ and $\epsilon > 0$ then $∃x ∈ S$ ∋ $x < M + \epsilon$
My solution is as follows,
$M = \inf S$ $⇒$ $M \le x$ $∀x$ 
$K$ lower bound ⇒ $K \le x$ $∀x$ 
Combining inequalities, 
($M \le x$) ∧ ($K \le x$) ⇒ ($M \le K \le x$) $∨$ $(K \le M \le x)$ $∀x$ 
Note that I use or here as we will soon see that both statements cannot be true. However, I am unsure how to prove from first principle's that the implication of an and statement is an or statement. Maybe the the consequent could be an and statement. Maybe it would be an idea to investigate this using a truth table and the laws of predicate logic.
Decomposing inequalities, 
$(a)$ $M \le K \le x$ $⇒$ $M \le K$ $∀x$ 
$(b)$ $K \le M \le x$ $⇒$ $K \le M$ $∀x$ 
I think of these inequalities decompositions as the antecedent is a general case of consequent, or equivalently, the consequent is a sub-case (special) case of the antecedent .
Decomposing $(a)$
$M \le K$ $⇒$ ($M = K$) $∨$ $(M < K)$ $∀x$ 
$M = \inf S$ $⇏$ $M < K$ $∀x$ 
$∴$ $M \le K$ $⇒$ $M \nleq K$ ⟺ $K > M$ $∀x$ 
However, does anybody please know where I should go from here?
Thanks!
**

Writing "$S\neq\varnothing\subseteq \mathbb{R}$" provides no information about $S$ other than that it is nonempty. If you are trying to say "$S$ is a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$" then you should write $\varnothing\neq S\subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

Thank you for your comment! I will edit the question.

If $M$ is the greatest lower bound of $S$, and $\epsilon\gt0$, then $M+\epsilon$ being greater then $M$ is not a lower bound of $S$. Since $M+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound of $S$, that means that $x\lt M+\epsilon$ for some $x\in S$.

By the way, the quantifier $\forall x$ is supposed to go on the left, not on the right. Better: instead of using the symbol $\forall$ write in English "for all $x$".

Thank you for your replies! Sorry why must the for all quantifier go on the left?

What's to prove?  This follows directly from the definion of $\inf$.  The definition of $\inf$ is that anything larger than $M$ can't be a lower bound. $M+\epsilon$ is larger than $M$ so $M +\epsilon$ can not be a lower bound. ANd the definition of lower bound would meant $M+\epsilon$ is less or equal to all terms in $S$ and as $M+\epsilon$ is not a lower bound there must be $x\in S$ that is less than $M+\epsilon$.

Thanks for your reply @fleablood! I agree, however, the question asks me to prove this fact. So maybe I should just say it follows from the definition of inf?

What's the text, and what definitions were you given?
